# Use previous item in foreach knockout binding

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following problem: I have an observable array (populated from the server), which looks like this:

```
this.elems = ko.observableArray([
    {n: 1, t : 'hello'},
    {n: 1, t : 'why'},
    {n: 1, t : 'are'},
    {n: 2, t : 'some'},
    {n: 2, t : 'ducks'},
    {n: 3, t : 'here'},
    {n: 8, t : '?'}
]);
```

And I want to show it in the following way:

```
      1
Hello
why
are
      2
some
ducks
      3
here
      8
?
```

As you see the number is shown only if the previous number is not the same as current.
This would be super easy with the `foreach` binding (here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/62Fz8/)).

```
<div data-bind="foreach: elems">
    <div class="t1">
        <span data-bind="text: n" class="c1"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: t" class="c2"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Only if I would be able to access previous the previous element. 
I know that I can modify my observalbe array and achieve what I want, but is there a way to do this without changing it?

Comment: What you should probably do is to, on your viewmodel, create a computed observable which performs the grouping. Otherwise you would end up with a hard time testing it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could access the $index and $parent values.  Try this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: elems">
    <div class="t1">
        <!-- ko if: $index() === 0 || $parent.elems()[$index() - 1].n !== n -->
        <span data-bind="text: n" class="c1"></span>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <span data-bind="text: t" class="c2"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

An alternative that uses visible binding instead:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: elems">
    <div class="t1">
        <span data-bind="text: n, visible: $index() === 0 || $parent.elems()[$index() - 1].n !== n" class="c1"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: t" class="c2"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, didn't see your answer before posting my own. +1

Answer (score 2):

If the `elems` property is dynamically loaded I'd suggest you use a `computed` observable to group the data and return an array with the groups.

So, given the following simple grouping function:

```
function groupArray(array, keyRetrieverFunc){
    var groupedArray = array.reduce(function(previous, item){
        var key = keyRetrieverFunc(item);
        if (previous[key]){
            previous[key].items.push(item);
        } else {
            previous[key] = { key: key, items: [
                item
            ]};
        }
        return previous;
    }, {});
    return groupedArray
}
```

we could create a viewmodel which looks like the following:

```
function ViewModel(){
    var self = this;

    self.elems = ko.observableArray([
        {n: 1, t : 'hello'},
        {n: 1, t : 'why'},
        {n: 1, t : 'are'},
        {n: 2, t : 'some'},
        {n: 2, t : 'ducks'},
        {n: 3, t : 'here'},
        {n: 8, t : '?'}
    ]);
    self.groupedElements = ko.computed(function(){
        var groups = {};
        var elements = self.elems();
        var groups = groupArray(elements, function(item){return item.n;});
        var results = [];
        for(var property in groups){
            results.push(groups[property]);
        }
        return results;
    });
}
```

Observe the groupedElements `computed` observable. This is the observable we will bind the DOM elements to.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: groupedElements">
    Group name: <span data-bind="text: key"></span>
    <div data-bind="foreach: items">
        <div data-bind="text: t"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When new data comes in and replaces the observed `self.elems` array, the `groupedElements` will automatically be updated, since the `computed` observable has subscribed to changes in the `self.elems` array.

I have his setup at the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/J6k54/.

Answer (score 1):

A. You have to change structure of your viewmodel
like :

```
function AppViewModel() {
this.elems = ko.observable([
    {n: 1, t : ['hello','why']},
    {n: 2, t : ['why','not']},
]);
```

}

```
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

B. And your html bindins will be :

```
<div data-bind="foreach: elems">
<div class="t1" >
    <span data-bind="text: n" class="c1"></span>
    <span data-bind="foreach: t">
        <br/>
        <span data-bind="text: $data" class="c2"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, but in my question I mentioned that I know how to do this, but I am currently looking solution which does not require schema change.

Comment: okay then you can loop through server data and create new js object for binding

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: elems">
    <div class="t1">
        <!-- ko if: ($index() === 0 
           || ($parent.elems()[$index()-1].n != $parent.elems()[$index()].n)) -->
        <span data-bind="text: n" class="c1"></span>
        <!--/ko-->
        <span data-bind="text: t" class="c2"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

See **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nyothecat/62Fz8/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this is to use underscore.js to transform your data structure

See this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/62Fz8/9/

The transformation function in underscore.js is really simple :

```
  _.chain(self.elems())
   .groupBy(function (o) { return o.n; })
   .map(function (o, key) { return { n: key,t: o };}).value();
```

Just wrap this function in a ko.computed function and bind to it directly.
This  will turn your array into a simple grouping, all you require then is the following data-binding :

```
<h1> What I you want to achieve </h1>
<div data-bind="foreach: groupedItems">
  <div class="t1"> 
        <span data-bind="text: n" class="c1"></span>
       <!--ko foreach:t -->
       <span data-bind="text: t" class="c2"></span>
       <!-- /ko -->
</div>
</div>
```